# Swift - screenshot of webview contents not working

Tags: swift

On click of a button, I'm taking screenshot.

My screen also has a Webview and screenshot doesn't include webview contents.

Here is the code:

```
var window: UIWindow? = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows[0]
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(window!.frame.size, false, 0.0)
window!.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
self.ScreenShotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Do I need to change anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the following code, designating where on the screen the screenshot should start:

```
view.drawHierarchy(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.size.width, height: view.bounds.size.height), afterScreenUpdates: true)
```

Put this code below **UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions**